# How do I execute a Jupyter notebook from an IPython shell?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

I have written a Jupyter notebook (a `.pynb` file), and I would like to continue my exploration of the data described in that notebook. I strongly prefer doing so in the IPython REPL rather than in the Jupyter notebook itself, so I would like to execute the whole notebook in the Jupyter REPL and populate the global namespace with all variables defined in the notebook.

I'm aware that I can export the notebook as a Python script and `%run` it, but that doesn't work because of magics such as `%matplotlib inline` that don't work in my IPython shell (running this on macOS).

In R, one can run a R Markdown notebook from the console with `rmarkdown::render()`, and have the global environment populated with the objects defined in the R Markdown notebook. Is there anything similar for IPython?

Comment: I think you mean "interact with the cells of an ipynb file," not run/ execute it?

Comment: What the user describes in the first paragraph is now possible in **JupyterLab** in a manner slightly differently than the OP envisioned. To achieve what the OP describes in the first paragraph, the notebook can be run as is typical within JupyterLab using `Run All` and then open a new 'Console' attached to this notebook'. There's actually several ways to get to that option. One is right-clicking in the notebook and choosing it from the list. (Actually [this video illustrates that as a way to introduce the code console](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eq1l7DBngQQ), and I'd suggest the OP ...

Comment: <continuing> check it out.) There are additional options to open the  'Console' from under the `'File`' menu. The behavior of the code console has some handy options that can be customized both by interacting with the console directly via right-click and in the advanced settings. A few of those options are discussed in the first three posts of [this exchange about console behavior as additional cells get run in the associated notebook](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/console-would-not-automatically-run-code-typed-in-notebook-kernel/12512?u=fomightez). Because these consoles are like ...

Comment: <continuing>  other JupyterLab tabs/windows in that you can arrange them as you wish, you can make the interface suit how you like to work, see [here for an example](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/is-it-possible-to-have-new-printouts-at-top-of-cell/12683/2?u=fomightez).

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if you could run it this way:

```
pip install runipy
$ runipy MyNotebook.ipynb
```

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter now has support for executing notebooks: https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html , which allows for something like:

```bash
jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute mynotebook.ipynb
```

There are loads of flags and runtime options which look like they provide lots of mileage.

Comment: Plus jupytext and papermill allow this with even more features; however, I don't think  command line based execution of the notebook was the real point of this post.